# Can you use an enemy as an improvised weapon in D&D 5th edition?

Tags: dnd-5e, improvised-weaponry

I play a 10th level Paladin Goliath and I want to pick up a Bandit Chief and smash him into his cronies … repeatedly. What are the rules regarding this situation? Also, can I Divine Smite with said Bandit Chief?

Any other thoughts from experienced DMs about types of feats and proficiency  that may be required would be appreciated.

Comment: Related, possible duplicate: [Can you pick up and use an enemy as an improvised weapon?](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95181/can-you-pick-up-and-use-an-enemy-as-an-improvised-weapon) Also, your secondary question about using Divine Smite with an improvised weapon is entirely different from your main question, and should probably be edited out and asked separately.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You can use dead enemies as much as you want - they're one of the examples given in the description of improvised weapons.

> An improvised
>   weapon includes any object you can wield in one or two
>   hands, such as broken glass, a table leg, a frying pan, a
>   wagon wheel, or a dead goblin.

It sounds like you want to use *living* enemies, though. These almost certainly can't be used as improvised weapons - an improvised weapon has to be an object, and creatures and objects are consistently two different things throughout the rules. There's lots of examples of this, but for completeness I'll give one, which comes from the very start of the PHB:

> Over the course of their adventures, the characters
>   are confronted by a variety of creatures, objects,
>   and situations that they must deal with in some way.

Ok, so the obvious option of just using an enemy as an improvised weapon is out. But you still want to hit one guy with another guy, right? Well, first, you're going to need to grapple them:

> When you want to grab a creature or wrestle with it, you
>   can use the Attack action to make a special melee attack,
>   a grapple.

This lets you grab them, and even pick them up:

> When you move, you
>   can drag or **carry** the grappled creature with you, but
>   your speed is halved, unless the creature is two or more
>   sizes smaller than you.

Cool, so we've picked up an enemy in one hand. Unfortunately, this is where the rules run out on us - there's no more specific guidance for what you want to do. We can fall back on the general guidance, though:

> When you describe an action not detailed elsewhere in
>   the rules, the DM tells you whether that action is possible
>   and what kind of roll you need to make, if any, to determine
>   success ar failure.

At this point, it's entirely up to your DM. Tell them that you want to hit an enemy with the creature you've picked up, and let them work out how to model that in the system. They may make it an attack roll, they may make it an ability check. They almost certainly won't make it a saving throw. While I could talk about how I'd handle it, there's not really any point - it's entirely in the hands of your DM.

As for the Paladin's Divine Smite:

> Starting at 2nd level, when you hit a creature with a
>   melee weapon attack, you can expend one paladin spell
>   slot to deal radiant damage to the target, in addition to
>   the weapon's damage.

The only requirement for a Divine Smite is that you hit with a melee weapon attack. So if your DM decides that this is a melee weapon attack, you can use Divine Smite with it. If they decide anything else, you can't.

Comment: worth thinking about mass-comparisons? my first thought on seeing the question was that the heaviest "heavy" weapon comes in at 12lb, and I'd use that as a touchstone for improvised weapons. (But then that line about the dead goblin came along....)

Comment: @nitsua60 In a game where a properly specced character can lift 1200 lb in one hand, I'm not going to worry about it. There's always room for another answer though :)

Comment: Just wondering: It says that you can attack with a weapon in your free hand if you're grappling, but does the hand holding a creature really count as free with a weapon?

Comment: I can't find the exact wording for 5e but from what I've read, a creature that is grappling can attack 'with a weapon in his free hand' or an unarmed attack. The hand that's grappling obviously does not count as a free hand. Also, it might be worth including whether improvised weapons can divine smite or not

Comment: you need a free hand to attack, either as an unarmed attack or with a weapon. The grappling rules I've read say that you can attack with a free hand while grappling, so it's safe to assume the other that is grappling does not count as a free hand anymore, therefore you cannot attack with the hand that is grappling a creature. http://www.enworld.org/forum/showthread.php?468737-The-Grappler-s-Manual-(2-0)-Grappling-in-5th-Edition#rules "You can make an attack roll with any weapon in your free hand." "Once the second enemy is grappled, you won't be able to do actions that require a free hand."

Comment: @Teco Ah, I see. That sounds like an alternative answer, not something that would form part of this one. Feel free to post it - it's a solid line of reasoning, and I'll upvote it, at least.

Comment: I'd rather not as I don't have any references to official D&D material, the dandwiki website has 3.5 grappling only. Do you know where I can find an SRD for 5e?

Comment: @Teco The hand that is occupied when grappling is the hand used to grapple the creature. The rule caters to cases where you want to attack with a weapon, not the creature you actually grapple. In that case, I would assume you wouldn't need a free hand. Logically, why would you need a free hand when the hand you want to attack with is already holding what you want to use?

Comment: @Teco Wizards isn't releasing anything as thorough as the SRD was, but they _have_ published a "basic" version of the rules that has most of the core rules in it, here: http://dnd.wizards.com/articles/features/basicrules

Comment: Re: the last point, Crawford has (unofficially) ruled in a tweet that the phrasing "in addition to the weapon's damage" means Divine Smite requires an attack with a weapon, not just any melee weapon attack. That said, the question of smiting with improvised weapons should probably be edited out of the original post anyway and asked separately.