# If an Eldritch Knight has a Weapon Bond with cat claws, when summoned, does the cat teleport with their claws?

Tags: dnd-5e, natural-weapon, eldritch-knight

Edward the Eldritch Knight can make a Weapon Bond, he can summon the weapon and it will teleport to his hand.

The Monsters Manual indicates that claws are natural weapons, and that natural weapons are weapons.

When Edward summons his claws, does the cat teleport with them?

Relevant Rules:

> **MELEE AND RANGED ATTACKS**
> The most common actions that a monster will take in combat are melee
> and ranged attacks. These can be spell attacks or weapon attacks where
> "weapon" might be a manufactured item or a natural weapon such as a
> claw or tail spike. *(MM p10)*
>
> **Weapon Bond** At 3rd level, you learn a ritual that creates a magical
> bond between yourself and one weapon... If it is on the same plane of
> existence, you can summon that weapon as a bonus action on your turn,
> causing it to teleport instantly to your hand. *(PHB p75)*
>
> **[Cat](https://www.dndbeyond.com/monsters/cat)**
> **Claws**. Melee Weapon Attack: +0 to hit, reach 5 ft., one target. Hit: 1
> slashing damage. *(Basic Rules p121)*

Answer (score -5, accepted):

**Yes, the entire cat is teleported instantly to the fighters hand.**

Summarily; the cats natural weapons (it’s claws) are integral to the cat and are not separated by teleportation or any means besides DM fiat or a lingering injury.

---

The Weapon Bond rule describes the weapon summoning as teleporting the weapon.

> Once you have bonded a weapon to yourself... If it is on the same plane
> of existence, you can summon that weapon as a bonus action on your
> turn, causing it to **teleport instantly to your hand**. *PHB 75*

There is no rule (that I am aware of) indicating an appendage of a creature can be teleported separately from the creature.

The only rules regarding separating appendages from creatures is an optional rule for lingering injuries (DMG 273) which stipulates criteria which would not be met in this case.

> - They take a critical hit
> - They are dropped to 0 HP but aren't killed
> - They fail a death saving throw by 5 or more

Since the natural weapon “Cat claws” is summoned and they can’t be separated from the ‘cat creature’ by teleportation, then the cat is transported whole.

The cats natural weapons are an appendage of the creature, the summoning teleports the natural weapon “Claws” but these claws are integral to the cat, so the cat itself is summoned.

To bring the point home I’ll make an analogy. When an Eldridge Knight summons a sword, the hilt and pommel are also teleported, even if they are very ornate.

Related:
Can an Eldritch Knight bond with natural weapons?
[This well reasoned answer indicates yes](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/a/164201/53875).

Answer (score 18):

## No, because those claws aren't a valid target in the first place

Natural weapons count as weapons for the creature they are attached to, it doesn't mean they're suddenly a valid weapon for everybody else. D&D doesn't have separate body parts, and as long as those claws are attached to that cat, they're considered part of a creature, not a weapon for you to pick up.

You could [perhaps wield the entire cat as an improvised weapon if it was willing and your DM agreed](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/95181/can-you-pick-up-and-use-an-enemy-as-an-improvised-weapon), and then you [may or may not be allowed to bond to it by your DM](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/69668/can-you-make-a-weapon-bond-with-an-improvised-weapon), in which case, yeah, enjoy your teleporting cat.

But as long as those claws are still attached to that cat, they are in no way a weapon for you and it'll require serious fudging with the rules to ever make it one.

Comment: Your answer probably goes a long way to answering [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/164168/35259) as well...

Comment: @NathanS In that case, the natural weapons are at least part of the Eldritch Knight so it's a different problem. I'm not really sure what the point is at that point because you're no longer able to teleport a cute cat with you at all times, but hey.

Comment: Anyone who owns a cat would know that if you tried to use its claws as a weapon against someone else, it would certainly be _you_ that ended up taking large amounts of damage!

Comment: Actually, that's a good point; that question does differ because the natural weapon is part of the EK at that point, rather than being a natural weapon of a different creature entirely.

Comment: @PJRZ Would likely be easier to use it as a club after the first couple of landed blows you wouldn't have to worry about the cat being angry.

Comment: Your idea 'weapons for the creature they are attached to' is not a valid game concept. 
In D&D there is a defined concept of 'weapons', period.

Comment: There is no 'weapon for you, dildo for me' in this game.